# How to resolve Microsoft Azure dependencies on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I'm trying to follow "How to run a compute-intensive task in Java" tutorial.
However, I'm stuck on the following step:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-java-run-compute-intensive-task/#how-to-create-a-java-application-that-performs-a-compute-intensive-task

Eclipse shows an error saying that these dependencies can't be resolved:

```
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.Configuration;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.ServiceException;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.*;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.serviceBus.models.*;`
```

I'm using Eclipse and I've downloaded the Azure toolkit for Eclipse.

Here's how my Eclipse project looks like:

[image: Project]

The code is simply a copy-paste of TSPSolver.java.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the issue was caused by missing some dependent libraries that you can try to add them via configure the `Java Build Path` or configure the `pom.xml` file in the Maven project to resolve it.

For the first way, adding the dependent libraries via configure the `Build Path`. You can download these libraries and their dependencies from the [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus/0.9.7).

1. Right click on the project name, then select `Build Path` and click `Configure Build Path`.
   [image]
2. Add these jar files via click `Add External Class Folder`
   [image]

For the second way, adding the maven dependencies in the `pom.xml` file.

1. Convert the current normal Eclipse Project into a Maven project.
   [image]
2. Open the `pom.xml` file in the project and add the below content from [link1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-core/0.9.7) & [link2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus/0.9.7).

   ```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
           <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
           <version>0.9.7</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
           <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
           <version>0.9.7</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking now, latest version are as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
```